# Setting an image as Navigation Bar title

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to set an image as the title of a navigation bar in swift using the code below. The code builds successfully, but the image does not display. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController { 

    @IBOutlet weak var navigationBar: UINavigationItem!
    var convoImage: UIImage!
    var convoImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.convoImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "conversation.png")
        self.convoImageView = UIImageView(image: self.convoImage)
        self.navigationBar.titleView = self.convoImageView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the navigationItem's titleView.

```
let image = UIImage(named: "image_name.png")
self.navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: image)
```

In your code replace below line:

```
self.convoImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "conversation.png")
```

with

```
self.convoImage = UIImage(named: "conversation.png")
```

Comment: I'm new to ios. So, what's the difference between them? I saw documentation. The only difference is cacheing the image. So, what's causing the problem?

Comment: Yes, but if you are using "contentsOfFile" than you need to provide Full Path of your image instead of "conversation.png"
Like:self.convoImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile:  "/Users/userName/Desktop/YourProjectName/conversation.png")
Olso you can drag image from project navigator to your code between "".

Comment: And second method is for the images inside bundle and first one is for the images outside the bundle.So, that's why we need to provide full path as said above.

Comment: @H-H and girish Now I understood!

Comment: @girishchovatiya haha... I'm not the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `convoImageView` frame .

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController { 

    @IBOutlet weak var navigationBar: UINavigationItem!
    var convoImage: UIImage!
    var convoImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.convoImage = UIImage(named: "conversation.png")
        self.convoImageView = UIImageView(image: self.convoImage)
        self.convoImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,720,100)
        self.navigationBar.titleView = self.convoImageView
    }
}
```